# node express how to render handlebars html page to file

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I want to convert some html page to pdf via wkhtmltopdf. However, the html page I want to convert to pdf is dynamically generated using handlebars.

So I think one solution maybe to generate the html page via handlebars but to a file (html file). Then, convert that file to pdf using hkhtmltopdf, then allow the user to, somehow, download the pdf.

So, my question is: how can I render the (handlebars) dynamically generated html page to a file?

Thanks and bye ...

Comment: check the first usage example from here https://npmjs.com/package/handlebars then write to your file with fs.writeFile

Comment: Hi, Miroshko, thanks for your answer; please see my comment below ...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Simple example for create file.

```
var Handlebars = require('handlebars');

var source = "<p>Hello, my name is {{name}}. I am from {{hometown}}. I have " +
    "{{kids.length}} kids:</p>" +
    "<ul>{{#kids}}<li>{{name}} is {{age}}</li>{{/kids}}</ul>";
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

var data = { "name": "Alan", "hometown": "Somewhere, TX",
    "kids": [{"name": "Jimmy", "age": "12"}, {"name": "Sally", "age": "4"}]};
var result = template(data);


var fs = require('fs');
    fs.writeFile("test.html", result, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, I'm a little confused here. First, I use: var exphbs = require('express-handlebars'). When I try to do "compile" I get this error: "Handlebars has no method 'compile'". I use this code in a different file from "main", where I configure Express using "create" method. I tried to add "create" part in this file, but error is the same. As I need this not in "main" but in another file (another.js), which I requiere from "main.js", What do I have to do for Handlebars to accept "compile" method ???

Comment: I think 'express-handlebars' is not official and full package. use this - https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars

Answer (score 4):

Using `express-handlebars`, you should use the advanced mode and create an instance of it like in [this example](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars/blob/master/examples/advanced/server.js#L12).

The proper way would be to create a view file (like you probably already have per you question) and use the express handlebars instance to render it:

```
// init code
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
var hbs = exphbs.create({
    defaultLayout: 'your-layout-name',
    helpers: require("path-to-your-helpers-if-any"),
});
app.engine('.file-extention-you-use', hbs.engine);
app.set('view engine', '.file-extention-you-use');

// ...then, in the router
hbs.render('full-path-to-view',conext, options).then(function(hbsTemplate){
     // hbsTemplate contains the rendered html, do something with it...
});
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Code above from Alex works perfect. However, my confusion was: I was using 'express-handlebars' and not 'handlebars'. Now, what I can understand is Express-Handlebars is an implementation of Handlebars for an Express application, which I´m using. I just didn't find a way to use the 'compile()' method in Express-Handlebars, so I ended up installing Handlebars (standalone) and used it to compile my (html) template and save the result to disk, just as Alex explained above.

In summary: 
1) I know Express-Handlebars is Handlebars for Express app. 
2) I don't know how to use "compile()" method just from express-handlebars, so I ended up installing Handlebars (from npm) and using it on the server to produce my html file (from template) and save it to disk. 
3) Of course I installed and use Express-Handlebars everywhere to serve my pages in my Express app; just installed Handlebars to produce my html (in the server) with "compile()" method and save the result to disk.

Hope this is understandable. Thanks again and bye ...

Comment: This should be just a comment, not another answer and you should accept Alex's answer if it is correct.