# Rendering a view without res.render

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

Following the documentation:

```
https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars
```

I have a need to compile a template, but not using the documented method of res.render('myView'), because in my context there is not res.

This is what I have so far:

```
var express = require('express')
    , exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
    , hbs = exphbs.create({
        extname: '.hbs',
        defaultLayout: 'default'
    });

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.engine('hbs', hbs.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

var tplVars = {
    id: 12345,
    name: 'John Doe'
  }

hbs.handlebars.compile( .. path to pdf.hbs ... )(vars);
```

Now, obviously I need to register the template. What is missing here?

My file structure in /views:

```
views/
    layouts/
      default.hbs
    partials/
      css.hbs
    pdf.hbs
```

Comment: Are you trying to render a template on app start? If so, you could always wrap the rendering in `app.use((req, res, next) => {res.render('view', data)})`

Comment: No, I'm not. The code above is taken out of context. What I'm after is how to compile a Handlebars template that has partials. I'm trying to AVOID using res.render - because in my context there is not res

Comment: I don't think you can compile templates with `express-handlebars` but you can do so with `handlebars`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30032819/710005

Comment: @SwarajGiri If you post your comment as an answer I will approve it, because you're right. This is a Handlebars job - not suitable for express-handlebars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy paste from the comment above.

I don't think you can compile templates with `express-handlebars`, but you can do so with `handlebars`.
Details in a previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30030551/node-express-how-to-render-handlebars-html-page-to-file/30032819#30032819).