# Node js - Compile handlebars view without rendering it

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, handlebars.js

My problem is simple: I want to compile a Handlebars view then not render it - instead I want to use the compiled HTML server side. While researching the problem, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30030551/node-express-how-to-render-handlebars-html-page-to-file) was the closest to my problem that I could find, but unless I'm misunderstanding, all their doing in this question is creating an HTML string server-side and populating it with data. It's insufficient because I don't want to create any HTML strings, I literally want to keep my HTML stored in `.hbs` files, as usual, and then compile a view (i.e. send it my variables), then instead of displaying it to a user (which won't be possible anyway because it's an API server only), I want to have the compiled HTML to send it on to Mailgun (but the fact that I want to send it to Mailgun is outside the scope, answers should preferably only tell me how to compile the view and be able to (for instance) `console.log()` the HTML).

I'm using Node v9.8.0

Packages:

- body-parser: 1.18.3
- cors: 2.8.4,
- dotenv: 5.0.1,
- express: 4.16.3,
- hbs: 4.0.1
- moment: 2.22.1

Let me know if I need to supply any additional information and the reason that I haven't included any example code of what I've tried is that I have literally no idea what to even try. All I've tried was `let emailHtml = res.render('email/contactReceipt.hbs', { name:req.body.name })` inside my route but that gave me the error `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`.

**Side Note:** I am fairly new to Node.js and it's not part of my normal stack. I have noticed that other people use the package 'express-handlebars' and even just 'handlebars' so if what I'm using ('hbs') is actually in no way related to Handlebars, or if I won't be able to accomplish what I'm trying to do because of it, let me know.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`res.render` accepts a third parameter which is a callback containing the rendered string, without sending a response, thus avoiding `Headers already sent` error

```
res.render(view [, locals] [, callback])
```

> Renders a view and sends the rendered HTML string to the client.
>   Optional parameters:
>
> - locals, an object whose properties define local variables for the
>     view.
> - **callback, a callback function**. If provided, the method returns
>     both the possible error and rendered string, but does not perform an
>     automated response. When an error occurs, the method invokes next(err)
>     internally.

```
res.render('email/contactReceipt.hbs', { name:req.body.name }, (err, html) => {
    if(err) 
       return console.error(err);
    // do whatever you want here with `html`
});
```

---

You can also use [app.render](http://expressjs.com/es/api.html#app.render) which is similar to `res.render` but works on a global level, and always takes a third parameter.

```
app.render('email/contactReceipt.hbs', { name:req.body.name }, (err, html) => {
    if(err) 
       return console.error(err);
    // do whatever you want here with `html`
});
```

---

Or you can just compile the template directly and do whatever you want later.

```
const hbs = require('hbs');

const template = hbs.compile('<h1>{{title}}</h1>');

const html = template({ title: 'Handlebars' });
console.log(html); // <h1>Handlebars</h1>
```

If you want to read the template content from disk, just use the `fs.readFile` and pass the content to `hbs.compile`

```
const hbs = require('hbs');
const fs = require('fs');
const readFile = require('util').promisify(fs.readFile);

async render(file, data) {
    const content = await readFile(file, 'utf8');
    // Implement cache if you want
    const template = hbs.compile(content);

    return template(data);
}
```

Comment: Okay cool, but here's the problem, I should probably have included this in my question, where you have `hbs.compile()` I want to give it the path to a file in my `views` directory, e.g. `hbs.comple('email/contact.hbs')`. Can that be done?

Comment: Just read the file content using `fs`, and pass it to handlebars, which is what `res.render` does.

Comment: Your a boss. I setup the `res.render()` the way you explained it and it worked. I tried the `readFile` way too but I wasn't sure where to put the `async` stuff, in my route? Outside my route, like a function? Not sure.. Anyway, thanks for the help, I think I can take it from here.

Comment: Added `app.render` function too. And `render` function should be put outside your route, and then make your route calback, an `async` one, so you can use `await` inside it. This isn't mandatory, since you can call `render.then()` but using `await` is much simpler.