# Save hbs render into a variable with nestjs

Tags: javascript, typescript, handlebars.js, nestjs

I use hbs to render some templates in my nestjs app, but I need to save the html renderized into variable and send it to a external API.

In docs (https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mvc) I only found how to send the render as a normal response, It works, but I don't know how to save the html as variable.

Comment: Maybe this will help: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30030551/node-express-how-to-render-handlebars-html-page-to-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have access to the generated HTML before sending it to the client you can use the third parameter of the response [render](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render) method:

*app.controller.ts*

```
import { Get, Controller, Res } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Response } from 'express';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  @Get()
  root(@Res() res: Response) {
    return res.render(
        'index',
        { message: 'Hello world!' },
        function (err, html) {
            // Here you have access to the generated HTML
            res.send(html)
        }
    );
  }
}
```